# How do I define a new variable with information from a class?

Tags: python, class, economics

I have a project in which I am asked to illustrate how a relationship between two variables changes, as I implement changes to another variable.

More specifically, I have an economic model considering a household with a female and male member, who jointly maximize utility by choosing their time use from:

1. Hours working in the market, L_M and L_F, at wage W_M and W_F
2. Hours working at home, H_M and H_F.

I am then asked to illustrate the relationship between H_M and H_F, i.e., `H_F/H_M`, when there are varying changes to an alpha parameter. The changes in the alpha parameter must be [0.25, 0.50, 0.75].

I have tried to define the relationship 'H_F/H_M' by calling it from a class given to me in a different .py file, where the whole economic model is set up.

The economic model is as follows:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class HouseholdSpecializationModelClass:

    def __init__(self):
        """ setup model """

        # a. create namespaces
        par = self.par = SimpleNamespace()
        sol = self.sol = SimpleNamespace()

        # b. preferences
        par.rho = 2.0
        par.nu = 0.001
        par.epsilon = 1.0
        par.omega = 0.5 

        # c. household production
        par.alpha = 0.5
        par.sigma = 1.0

        # d. wages
        par.wM = 1.0
        par.wF = 1.0
        par.wF_vec = np.linspace(0.8,1.2,5)

        # e. targets
        par.beta0_target = 0.4
        par.beta1_target = -0.1

        # f. solution
        sol.LM_vec = np.zeros(par.wF_vec.size)
        sol.HM_vec = np.zeros(par.wF_vec.size)
        sol.LF_vec = np.zeros(par.wF_vec.size)
        sol.HF_vec = np.zeros(par.wF_vec.size)

        sol.beta0 = np.nan
        sol.beta1 = np.nan

    def calc_utility(self,LM,HM,LF,HF):
        """ calculate utility """

        par = self.par
        sol = self.sol

        # a. consumption of market goods
        C = par.wM*LM + par.wF*LF

        # b. home production
        H = HM**(1-par.alpha)*HF**par.alpha

        # c. total consumption utility
        Q = C**par.omega*H**(1-par.omega)
        utility = np.fmax(Q,1e-8)**(1-par.rho)/(1-par.rho)

        # d. disutlity of work
        epsilon_ = 1+1/par.epsilon
        TM = LM+HM
        TF = LF+HF
        disutility = par.nu*(TM**epsilon_/epsilon_+TF**epsilon_/epsilon_)
        
        return utility - disutility

    def solve_discrete(self,do_print=False):
        """ solve model discretely """
        
        par = self.par
        sol = self.sol
        opt = SimpleNamespace()
        
        # a. all possible choices
        x = np.linspace(0,24,49)
        LM,HM,LF,HF = np.meshgrid(x,x,x,x) # all combinations
    
        LM = LM.ravel() # vector
        HM = HM.ravel()
        LF = LF.ravel()
        HF = HF.ravel()

        # b. calculate utility
        u = self.calc_utility(LM,HM,LF,HF)
    
        # c. set to minus infinity if constraint is broken
        I = (LM+HM > 24) | (LF+HF > 24) # | is "or"
        u[I] = -np.inf
    
        # d. find maximizing argument
        j = np.argmax(u)
        
        opt.LM = LM[j]
        opt.HM = HM[j]
        opt.LF = LF[j]
        opt.HF = HF[j]

        # e. print
        if do_print:
            for k,v in opt.__dict__.items():
                print(f'{k} = {v:6.4f}')

        return opt

    def solve(self,do_print=False):
        """ solve model continously """

        pass    

    def solve_wF_vec(self,discrete=False):
        """ solve model for vector of female wages """

        pass

    def run_regression(self):
        """ run regression """

        par = self.par
        sol = self.sol

        x = np.log(par.wF_vec)
        y = np.log(sol.HF_vec/sol.HM_vec)
        A = np.vstack([np.ones(x.size),x]).T
        sol.beta0,sol.beta1 = np.linalg.lstsq(A,y,rcond=None)[0]
    
    def estimate(self,alpha=None,sigma=None):
        """ estimate alpha and sigma """

        pass
```

My question is... *How do I illustrate what happens with the relationship H_F/H_M when I change the parameter alpha by the given values?*

I have tried to call the model in my .ipynb file, i.e.:

```
from HouseholdSpecializationModel import HouseholdSpecializationModelClass
model = HouseholdSpecializationModelClass
```

But from here on I am stuck as to what to do. Please keep in mind that I have used Python and VSC for a week or two :)

I hope someone can help me with this! Let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code:

```
from HouseholdSpecializationModel import HouseholdSpecializationModelClass
model = HouseholdSpecializationModelClass()
```

You are initialising an instance of the class. Notice that since the brackets are empty, the class does not allow for much customization. As such, you should change the init method as such:

```
class HouseholdSpecializationModelClass:

def __init__(self,rho,nu,epsilon,omega,alpha,sigma):
    """ setup model """

    # a. create namespaces
    par = self.par = SimpleNamespace()
    sol = self.sol = SimpleNamespace()

    # b. preferences
    par.rho = rho
    par.nu = nu
    par.epsilon = epsilon
    par.omega = omega 

    # c. household production
    par.alpha = alpha
    par.sigma = sigma
```

Then, you will have the same class but will be able to initialise it with different model parameters. For example, to match the hard-coded values:

```
model = HouseholdSpecializationModelClass(2.0,0.001,1.0,0.5,0.5,1.0)
```

Once you have the model initialised with the parameters of interest, you can use some of the class methods (functions). To solve the model, it appears you should use solve_discrete(), which you would do as:

```
opt = model.solve_discrete()
```

Opt is a container of the solution objects of interest. You can repeat this process for different values of alpha and compare.